# Updating Text on Label from Class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to create classes to help organize my code better rather than have a giant string of different functions, the function calls on my form load, but it doesn't actually apply the update to the label (Label still reads `label1`)
My Class Code is

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class DynamicDisplayHandler
    {


        public void LoadLastServer()
        {
            Form1 homepage = new Form1();
            MessageBox.Show("Loaded Class");

            if (File.Exists("./WTF/Config.wtf"))
            {
                int counter = 0;
                string line;


                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("./WTF/Config.wtf");
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("SET realmName"))
                    {

                        string converted = line.Replace("SET realmName", "");
                        string finalized = converted.Replace("\"", "");

                        homepage.lastServer.Text = finalized;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        homepage.lastServer.Text = "Never Connected";
                    }

                    counter++;
                }

                file.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                homepage.lastServer.Text = "";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now for my actual `Form1` file code I have

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
       public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DynamicDisplayHandler displayHandler = new DynamicDisplayHandler();
            displayHandler.LoadLastServer();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you do `Form1 homepage = new Form1();` in `LastLoadServer()`, you're in trouble. The new Form you just created has nothing to do with the original Form that called the method.

Pass a reference in instead:

```
public void LoadLastServer(Form1 homepage)
{
    ...
}
```

And call it accordingly:

```
displayHandler.LoadLastServer(this);
```

Comment: Yes, at least in the last day it is the 2nd question with such mistake that I have seen.

Comment: @GrantWinney, Thanks a ton. I've only just started toying with C# and I'm used to PHP where you don't need to set Arguments (Makes life easier, but not needed) Whereas it seems C# may be very argumentative in nature. :P Your solution worked very nicely. Now I can start some massive cleanup.

Comment: Thank ya. Just learned that throwing the counter in there during the while statement can end up being a very annoying program!

Comment: @MorganGreen By the way, You can also vote for an answer when you [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) it. It's not compulsory at all, but reasonable and recommended. You can vote for as many answers as you find helpful, including the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Form instance in the class is not the instance you see, you new it. Correct it like this, pass the instance by constructor.

```
class DynamicDisplayHandler
{
    public void LoadLastServer(Form1 f1)
    {
        Form1 homepage = f1;
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DynamicDisplayHandler displayHandler = new DynamicDisplayHandler();
        displayHandler.LoadLastServer(this); //
    }
}
```